# Converting MySQL to db_select with subquery count

Tags: 7, database

I have an SQL query, with subquery, that returns as set of nodes ordered by referenced nodes... It works fine in a `db_query`, but I need it to be dynamic, and it feels like a better idea to use Drupal's abstraction layer.

I have got so far, but I am having issues with the subquery. It doesn't appear to having any effect...

I should say I used the [Query Coder](https://www.drupal.org/project/query_coder) module to help do the conversion.

**SQL**:

```
SELECT n.nid , dest.field_flight_hero_destination_tid  hero_desintation_tid , (
SELECT COUNT( * )
FROM {field_data_field_field_route_matrix} routes
LEFT JOIN  {field_data_field_flight_destination} destination ON routes.field_field_route_matrix_target_id = destination.entity_id
WHERE routes.entity_id = n.nid
AND  field_flight_destination_tid
IN (:stopovers_tids)
)total
FROM node n
LEFT JOIN  field_data_field_flight_hero_destination dest ON n.nid = dest.entity_id
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_flight_price_matrix prices ON n.nid = prices.entity_id
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_flight_cabin_class class ON n.nid = class.entity_id
WHERE dest.field_flight_hero_destination_tid = :destination_tid AND class.field_flight_cabin_class_tid IN (:class_tid)
ORDER BY total DESC
```

**db_select**:

```
// Subquery.
  $subquery  = db_select('{field_data_field_field_route_matrix}', 'routes');
  $subquery->addExpression('COUNT(*)', 'count');
  $subquery->leftJoin('{field_data_field_flight_destination}', 'destination', 'routes.field_field_route_matrix_target_id = destination.entity_id');
  $subquery->condition('routes.entity_id', 'n.nid');
  $subquery->condition('field_flight_destination_tid', $stopovers);

  // Main query sorted by subquery.
  $query = db_select('node', 'n');
  $query->fields('n', array('nid'));
  $query->fields('dest', array('field_flight_hero_destination_tid'));
  $query->addJoin('', $subquery, 'total');
  $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_flight_hero_destination', 'dest', 'n.nid = dest.entity_id');
  $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_flight_price_matrix', 'prices', 'n.nid = prices.entity_id');
  $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_flight_cabin_class', 'class', 'n.nid = class.entity_id');
  $query->condition('dest.field_flight_hero_destination_tid', $destination);
  if (!empty($cabin_class)) {
    $query->condition('class.field_flight_cabin_class_tid', array($cabin_class), 'IN');
  }
$query->orderBy('total.count', 'DESC');
$result = $query->execute();
```

**Generated output**:

```
[queryString] => SELECT n.nid AS nid, dest.field_flight_hero_destination_tid AS field_flight_hero_destination_tid
FROM 
node n
 JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM 
field_data_field_field_route_matrix routes
LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_flight_destination destination ON routes.field_field_route_matrix_target_id = destination.entity_id
WHERE  (routes.entity_id = :db_condition_placeholder_1) AND (field_flight_destination_tid IN  (:db_condition_placeholder_2)) ) total
LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_flight_hero_destination dest ON n.nid = dest.entity_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_flight_price_matrix prices ON n.nid = prices.entity_id
WHERE  (dest.field_flight_hero_destination_tid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) 
ORDER BY total.count DESC
)
```

**Devel dpq**:

```
SELECT n.nid AS nid, dest.field_flight_hero_destination_tid AS field_flight_hero_destination_tid
FROM 
{node} n
 JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM 
{field_data_field_field_route_matrix} routes
LEFT OUTER JOIN {field_data_field_flight_destination} destination ON routes.field_field_route_matrix_target_id = destination.entity_id
WHERE  (routes.entity_id = 'n.nid') AND (field_flight_destination_tid IN  ('31', '366')) ) total
LEFT OUTER JOIN {field_data_field_flight_hero_destination} dest ON n.nid = dest.entity_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN {field_data_field_flight_price_matrix} prices ON n.nid = prices.entity_id
WHERE  (dest.field_flight_hero_destination_tid = '86') 
ORDER BY total.count DESC
```

Comment: db_select has the curly braces around it '{'... eg: '{field_data_field_field_route_matrix}'.. ??

Comment: Hmm... didn't notice that, but removing them has no effect.

Comment: Just to make sure, you removed them from the left join in your subquery as well?

Comment: did you install the Devel module and do `dpq($query)` to see what output drupal is generating for your `db_select` ?

Comment: Yes. It is as if the subquery wasn't there at all.

Comment: @tenken, I don't have access to Devel (long story) but I have updated the question with the generated query string.

Comment: @tenken, I have managed to get access to Devel and have attached to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your adding the subquery via a `join`. you want the subquery to be run as piece of the outermost `Select` statement, which Drupal 7 `SelectQuery` cannot do see:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214014/how-do-i-place-a-sub-query-in-a-select-statement-in-drupal7

The easiest way to do this to use `db_query` (a string) or maybe `hook_query_alter` after adding a tag to the `db_select` query and adding in the subquery via a string  later. If you need additional info passed in and out the `hook_query_alter` then use the metadata options.

Comment: Thanks @tenken. I added the subquery SQL with `addExpression`, and it appears to have worked wonderfully.